# Can an Ethereum account be used by several users at the same time?

Tags: dapps, accounts

I am developing a DApp for donations (the donations are not in cryptocurrencies). I want the donor to make donations without registering on the platform. In fact, I don't need to know who he is. So it is not worth creating a blockchain account for each donor.

Hence, I wonder if I can create a single blockchain account (universal account) that several donors use it to deposit their donations.

Is it possible? and if possible is it scalable (in the case where several donors deposit donations at the same time)

Comment: Does it make sense to you that a bunch of different donors (`senders` in the title of your question) will withdraw from the same bank account in order to deposit a donation somewhere?

Comment: In fact, the donations are not cryptocurrencies

Comment: @A.Gh How will the donors use the account? It is not uncommon for a project to use a special address to help onboarding. I'd ask why do you want to use smart contracts for something like that?

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder if I can create a single blockchain account (universal account) that several donors use it to deposit their donations.

Of course, just choose a random private key, generate the corresponding address and publish it.

---

> I don't need to know who he is. So it is not worth creating a blockchain account for each donor.

You don't need to create any account for any donor regardless of whether or not you know them.

Each donor needs to have their own account, with sufficient funds to donate from.

---

More seriously, it sounds like your a little confused about how things work.

Forget the blockchain for a moment. Does it make sense to you that several **different** donors (`senders` in the title of your question) will withdraw from **the same** bank account in order to deposit a donation somewhere? Each donor needs to have their own bank account, and it is obviously not up to you to create it for them.

In short, the scheme is of different donors **withdrawing** from different accounts and **depositing** to some other (single) account. You can create that account and ask them to deposit into it, but each one of them still needs to own his/her account to withdraw from.

Comment: I already mentioned that the donations are not in cryptocurrencies. So, I think it is not an obligation to create an account for each donor as he will not withdraw from it.